# Sumar el indice de una matriz en C#

Tags: c#

estoy en un curso de C# trate de resolver el siguiente ejercicio, estoy estancado no lo puedo resolver mire los videos los volvi a mirar miro el repositorio de GitHub pero nada no logro encontrar la solucion, dejo la consigna y el codigo que escribi.

Ejercicio

Crear un programa que cumpla con los siguientes pasos
Consigna

1. Crear una matriz de dos dimensiones de tipo int llamada números,
2. Determinar el tamaño de cada dimensión (fila, columnas) mediante valores ingresados por pantalla
3. Declarar un vector de tipo double llamado promedios
4. Recorrer la matriz para su carga con elementos de tipo int
5. Recorrer la matriz para mostrar cada valor de la matriz
6. Calcular el promedio de cada columna y asignarlo a la posición correspondiente dentro del vector promedios
7. Mostrar los promedios recorriendo el vector promedios

Me faltan resolver el punto tres, seis y siete.

3. Declarar un vector de tipo double llamado promedios
4. Calcular el promedio de cada columna y asignarlo a la posición correspondiente dentro del vector promedios
5. Mostrar los promedios recorriendo el vector promedios

Codigo

```
Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de Columnas: ");
// Determina las Columnas
int cantidadColumnas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de Filas: ");
// Determina las Filas
int cantidadFilas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("==============================================");

// Tipo[,] nombre = new tipo[cantidadFilas, cantidadColumnas]
int[,] numeros = new int[cantidadFilas, cantidadColumnas];
//Cantidad de filas
int lengthFilas = numeros.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
//Cantidad de columnas
int lengthColumnas = numeros.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

//Recorremos columnas y le asignamos un valor
for (int columna = 0; columna < lengthColumnas; columna++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"Valor de la columna {columna + 1}: ");

    // Recorremos filas y le asignamos un valor
    for (int fila = 0; fila < lengthFilas; fila++)
    {
        Console.Write($"Valor de la fila {fila + 1}: ");
        numeros[fila, columna] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("=======================================");

// Recorremos las columnas y las mostramos en pantalla
for (int columna = 0; columna < lengthColumnas; columna++)
{

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Valor de la Columna: {columna + 1}: ");

    // Recorremos filas y las mostramos en pantalla
    for (int fila = 0; fila < lengthFilas; fila++)
    {
        Console.Write($"Valor de la Fila: {fila + 1}: ");
        Console.WriteLine(numeros[fila, columna]);

    }
}


Console.WriteLine($"El promedio de los numeros es; {cantidadColumnas}");



Console.ReadKey(); 

introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: y cual problema tuviste al declarar un vector igual a todos los otros que declaraste?

Comment: no se como hacer el punto tres, cuatro y cinco.

Comment: no sabes como declarar un vector??? pero ya declaraste uno en tu codigo!!!